# Lyapunov theory in coupled nonlinear dynamic system with input

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations, stability

Suppose I have the following nonlinear coupled dynamic system

\begin{align*}
&\dot{x}_1 = f_1(x_1,x_2)\\
&\dot{x}_2 = f_2(x_2) + u
\end{align*}where $x_1\in \mathbb{R}^{n_1}$, $x_2\in \mathbb{R}^{n_2}$, and $u\in \mathbb{R}^{n_2}$. Suppose $f(0,0)=0$ and $u$ is the control input.

Suppose I want to study the stability of the above system w.r.t the state  $\textbf{x}_1$ **only** at the $x_1=0$. So consider $V(x_1)$ and suppose that

1. $V(x_1)>0$ for all $x_1 \neq 0$ and $V(x_1)=0$ if $x_1=0$.
2. $\dot{V}(x_1)=(\nabla_{x_1}V)^T \dot{x}_1=(\nabla_{x_1}V)^Tf_1$.

Now, I am confused how to proceed.

1. If $\dot{V}(x_1)=(\nabla_{x_1}V)^T \dot{x}_1=(\nabla_{x_1}V)^Tf_1<0$ for all $x_1 \neq 0$, then can we still say that the system is stable w.r.t $x_1$ at $x_1=0$?
2. The point I am confused is that the control input affect $x_2$ directly; however, $u$ affect $x_1$ by $x_2$. So not sure how to use the Lyapunov theory  here correctly.

Can anyone advise me this or refer me  some related reference/paper?

Thanks!

Comment: You need  to be careful in defining what you even mean by stability here. Several options come to mind: uniform with respect to $(x_2,u)$, input-to-state stable with respect to $u$.... In any case, $\dot V$ will depend on both $(x_1,x_2)$, as you will note, when you complete your formula in 2. So Question 1 is misguided. For Question 2, read: Sontag, Eduardo D. Input to state stability: Basic concepts and results. In: Nonlinear and optimal control theory. Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg, 2008. p. 163-220. This might give you an idea, what kind of questions can be asked here.